# Tabulator js custom column calculations done server side

Tags: javascript, tabulator

I'm trying to implement custom calculation function to get grand totals rather than totals of the data being displayed on the page but looks like there's no easy way to implement server-side calculations, but rather looks like you need to do everything in a function with the data associated with the table which is only a subset of records.

I tried implementing this via AJAX to get these totals done on the database side. Below is my code and that's just a generic function to get the count of all records including any filters, however this is not waiting for AJAX call and just returns 0.

First function

```
const buildCalculations = () => {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
        try {
            let result = apex.server.process("TOTAL_COUNT", {
                x01: params,
                pageItems: ["P1000_VIEW_NAME"]
            });

            result.done(function(data){          
                resolve(data.count);
            }).fail(function( jqXHR, textStatus, err ) {
                console.error(err);
            });
        } catch(error) {
            reject(error);
        }
  });
}
buildCalculations().then(
    function(value) {
        count = value;
    }
);
return count;
```

I then tried a different async/await even though the above returns a promise as well and should wait for the AJAX call to finish.

Second function.

```
async function buildCalculations() {
    let promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        let ssv = apex.server.process("COUNT", {
            x01: params,
            pageItems: ["P1000_VIEW_NAME"]
        });

        ssv.done(function(data){
            resolve(data.count);
        });
    });
    let result = await promise;
    return result;
}

buildCalculations().then(function(value) {
  return value; 
});
```

I then tried returning the summary data for all columns with grand total as part of the main fetch data request for the table with limited success as it works only when I call the first view/table after that the information totals row on the table is blank even though I see the data being processed accordingly on the custom calculation.

```
let column, total = "";
if (totals !== undefined) {
    Object.entries(totals).forEach((entry) => {
        const [key, value] = entry;
        total = value.value;
    });
}
return total;
```

This would be a much better option instead of having to do extra AJAX requests to get the summary data for each column that has a calculation especially when you don't have access to the column for which the calculation is being executed. Maybe I would need to pass the column/field via calcParams from the column definition, but still the main problems in calling AJAX requests from custom calculation remains which is why I started testing with only the total record count.